# If $f(U)=0$ then what is possible?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity

Let , $U=\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\times \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $V=\left(-\frac{1}{2},0\right)\times \left(-\frac{1}{2},0\right)$ and $D$ be the open unit disk centered at origin of $\mathbb R^2$ . Let , $f$ be real valued continuous function on $D$ such that $f(U)=0$. Then

(A) $f(v)=0$ for every $v\in V$.

(B) $f(v)\not=0$ for every $v\in V$.

(C) $f(v)=0$ for some $v\in V$.

(D) $f$ can assume every real value in $V$.

> Here , $f$ is continuous and $f$ has uncountably many zeros in $D$. then , $f$ may or may not be zero in $V$. So I think all (A) , (B) , (C) are possible. I am confused about my mistake.

Comment: I think that option (D) is the best because it precisely states that function $f$ can be really arbitrary in $V$. For each other option a counter-example could be constructed.

Comment: OK....But how you can say that  $f$ assume every real value in $V$ ?

Answer (score 0):

A) is possible. Just take $f\equiv 0.$

(B) is possible. Let $f(x,y) = 0$ if $x\ge 0, f(x,y) = x,x<0.$

(C ) is possible. See (A).

(D) is not possible. That's because $V$ is contained in a compact subset of $D.$ Therefore $f$ is bounded on $D.$

Comment: I think by "every real value," they might mean "any real value."  Certainly you cannot *conclude* (A), (B), or (C).  I admit the problem seems vaguely worded; for instance, we do not know whether "is it possible" is in the actual problem statement, or just the OP's title.